# Rebuild project in Android Studio MD5 hash

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am getting this message when I try to Rebuild my project but when I run the project everything works well, please any help?

```
Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'mockableAndroidJar' property 'outputFile' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'mockable-android-25.jar'.
```